# How Do Replace Phone.apk

Tags: android

I'm trying to mod Phone.apk.  I can build it using mm/mmm but re-install on phone fails.  I tried killing process com.android.phone first but that doesn't work either.  (I think the Phone is automatically restarted by some entity). Any ideas on how to replace Phone.apk on a running device?
Thanks in advance.
-John

Comment: Maybe the same will work if you root your phone?

Comment: Phone *is* rooted.  I forgot to mention that.

Comment: System apps are signed with the special signature and have to be run with user=system group=system to access specific internal permissions

Comment: Thanks, Andrey, that helped.  If you like, please submit this as a formal answer so I can give you "answer" credits.

Answer (score 0):

Use adb:

```
adb uninstall com.android.phone
```

Comment: Nope, no joy: returns "Failure"

Answer (score 0):

go to flight mode on and replace mod phone.apk and reboot and go to normal mode it will work

always backup your files before replacing